# How to split part of string

Tags: c#

I have this string

```
  1 3 9 13 38 40 52 54 59 98 107 113:274:8 8 9 5 20 5 25 14 5 10 10
```

I  need to split numbers so  use this code

```
                string[] lineElements = lines[i].Split(' ');
```

but I don't want numbers after first " : "
I only want to split this

```
 1 3 9 13 38 40 52 54 59 98 107 113
```

what can I do?

Comment: You can use the `string.Spilt` function to split string on ":"

Comment: i need to split all numbers but all numbers before " : "

Comment: @sepideh none blocks you to call Split two times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer, use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

```
string[] lineElements = lines[i].Split(':')[0].Split(' ');
```

You may have issues if the string does not contain :, but I do not think so since you only want the first string.